# very large A divide at a very large B

Tags: c++

I have already made a function of multiplication of long numbers, addition of long numbers, subtraction of long numbers and division of long numbers. But division takes a very long time, how it could be improved? Here is my code:

```
        /// removes unnecessary zeros
        vector<int> zero(vector<int> a)
        {
            bool f=false;
            int size=0;
            for(int i=a.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                if(a[i]!=0)
                {
                    f=true;
                    size=i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(f)
            {
                vector<int> b(size+1);
                for(int i=0;i<size+1;i++)
                    b[i]=a[size-i];

                return b;
            }
            else
                return a;


        }
        /// a+b
        vector<int> sum(vector<int> a,vector<int> b)
        {


            if(a.size()>b.size())
            {
                vector<int> rez(3000);
                int a_end=a.size()-1;
                int remainder=0,k=0,ans;
                for(int i=b.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    ans=a[a_end]+b[i]+remainder;

                    if(ans>9)
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans%10;
                        remainder=ans/10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                        remainder=0;
                    }
                    k++;
                    a_end--;
                }

                int kk=k;
                for(int i=a.size();i>kk;i--)
                {
                    ans=a[a_end]+remainder;

                    if(ans>9)
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans%10;
                        remainder=ans/10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                        remainder=0;
                    }
                    k++;
                    a_end--;
                }

                if(remainder!=0)
                {
                    rez[k]=remainder;
                }

                return zero(rez);

            }
            else
            {
                vector<int> rez(3000);
                int b_end=b.size()-1;
                int remainder=0,k=0,ans;
                for(int i=a.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    ans=b[b_end]+a[i]+remainder;

                    if(ans>9)
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans%10;
                        remainder=ans/10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                        remainder=0;
                    }
                    k++;
                    b_end--;
                }

                int kk=k;
                for(int i=b.size();i>kk;i--)
                {
                    ans=b[b_end]+remainder;

                    if(ans>9)
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans%10;
                        remainder=ans/10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                        remainder=0;
                    }
                    k++;
                    b_end--;
                }

                if(remainder!=0)
                {
                    rez[k]=remainder;
                }

                return zero(rez);

            }


        }

        /// a & b comparison
        int compare(vector<int> a,vector<int> b)
        {
            if(a.size()>b.size())
                return 1;
            if(b.size()>a.size())
                return 2;

            int r=0;

            for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
            {
                if(a[i]>b[i])
                {
                    r=1;
                    break;
                }
                if(b[i]>a[i])
                {
                    r=2;
                    break;
                }

            }

            return r;
        }

        /// a-b
        vector<int> subtraction(vector<int> a,vector<int> b)
        {

                vector<int> rez(1000);
                int a_end=a.size()-1;
                int k=0,ans;

                for(int i=b.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    ans=a[a_end]-b[i];

                    if(ans<0)
                    {
                        rez[k]=10+ans;

                        a[a_end-1]--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                    }
                    k++;
                    a_end--;
                }

                int kk=k;
                for(int i=a.size();i>kk;i--)
                {
                    ans=a[a_end];

                    if(ans<0)
                    {
                        rez[k]=10+ans;

                        a[a_end-1]--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rez[k]=ans;
                    }
                    k++;
                    a_end--;
                }


                return zero(rez);

        }

        /// a div b
        vector<int> div(vector<int> a,vector<int> b)
        {
            vector<int> rez(a.size());
            rez=a;
            int comp=-1;
            vector<int> count(1000);
            vector<int> one(1);
            one[0]=1;

            while(comp!=0 || comp!=2)
            {
                comp=compare(rez,b);
                if(comp==0)
                    break;

                rez=subtraction(rez,b);
                count=sum(count,one);
            }
            count=sum(count,one);
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: If it's production code I would use a 3rd party BigInt/BigNumeric lib. I suppose there are some good, optimized library on the internet.

Comment: @palacsint, thanks, but i want to do it without any libs

Comment: @KamilHismatullin, don't. Use libs. The only reason not to use an external library is for learning purposes.

Comment: Echo @WinstonEwert assertion. But do you just want comments on the division or do you want us to comment on the state of the rest of the code.

Comment: Have you considered breaking down the problem into subproblems involving powers of 2, and then using bit-shifting to perform the bit arithmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try implementing long division.

Example:
13587643180765 / 153483

1) Find first dividend:

**1358764**3180765 / 153483     #1358764 > 153483

2) Divide it by divisor (e.g by repeated subtraction, like you are doing

1358764 / 153483 = 8

3) Find the remainder (could be the result of previous computation)

1358764 % 153483 = 130900

4) Bring down the next digit to the end of the remainder.

135876**4**3180765
130900**4**

Repeat steps 2-4 until you have reached the last digit in the dividend.

---

Since 13587643180765 / 153483 = 88528652, it would take that many subtractions your way.

With long division, there's going to be at most 9 * digits_in_quotient subtractions (in step 2), in this case at most 8 * 9 = 72 subtractions (and in fact 8+8+5+2+8+6+5+2 = 44 subtractions)

Answer (score 1):

I would do a binary search on the answer. Roughly: you know `a/b` is between `0` and `a`. So just pretend you're looking for the answer in that range. For each guess `g`, compute the product `b*g`. If it's bigger than `a`, try something smaller on your next guess; otherwise, try something bigger on your next guess. The number of multiplications you have to make will be logarithmic in `a`. I don't think this would be much slower than long division, and conceptually it's much easier (less error-prone).